# In the memory, how would I tell a section is from program or from static lib?

Tags: assembly, operating-system

As you can see from the following image, programs (in this case, program1 and program 2) are mapped into memory while running. So I look at the assembly code, is there any clue that can tell the `boundary` between program1/2 and StaticLib?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Generally, no. Once linked you have no idea.

Comment: This diagram is COMPLETELY nonsensical. You something "staticlib" but it is shown as an object file. Yes, you could do that but it is not normally done because it is a wasteful approach. 

Object file do not reside in memory. Object files are linked as executable (or shared libraries). 

This just looks like a confusing Gee-Wiz diagram.

Answer (score -1):

IIRC it depends on the OS and file format.
On Windows, static library functions are usually referenced by a

```
call @xyz
```

to the address

```
@xyz: jmp RealAddress
```

(which contains the real address of the function).
So usually there is an area with these `JMP`s in the file. And all of those `JMP` targets are part of a linked library.